# Getting invalid index and empty tuple error

Tags: amazon-web-services, indexing, collections, count, terraform

I am trying to attach the target groups to the load balancer in terraform and I am getting the below error:

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "mytargetgroup" {
  count = var.environment_acronym == "pd" ? 1 : 0
  name                    = "My Target Group"
  port                    = 80
  protocol                = "HTTP"
  vpc_id                  = var.vpc_main_id
```

}

```
    resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "mytargetgroup_attachment" {
      target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.mytargetgroup[0].arn  --> having issues here
      target_id        = var.private_admin
      port             = 80
   }
```

Error: Invalid index
on lb_tg_attachments\lb_public_myloadbalancer_attach.tf line 70, in resource
"aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "mytargetgroup_attachment":
70:   target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.mytargetgroup[0].arn
├────────────────
│ aws_lb_target_group.mytargetgroup is empty tuple

```
  The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

How can I avoid this error. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I've noticed that all almost your questions got answered yet not a single answer was [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979). Accepting useful answers is not only a good practice, but reduces duplicates and increases chances of your questions being actually answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition `var.environment_acronym == "pd"` must be false, so `aws_lb_target_group` does not exist. Thus it does not work. You have to check for it later on as well:

```
    resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "mytargetgroup_attachment" {
      count = var.environment_acronym == "pd" ? 1 : 0

      target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.mytargetgroup[0].arn  --> having issues here
      target_id        = var.private_admin
      port             = 80
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin for your suggestion. Removing count is taking care of invalid index error. But how can I process if I get two or more targets with out using count. please advise.

Comment: @PrakashS Not sure what you mean. You can also use for_each. You can make new question specific to the new issue of multiple targets.